# Swift Convert number to text

Tags: string, text, swift

```
let winddir  = jsonResult["deg"]? as? Double
var val = ((winddir! / 22.5) + 0.5);
var arr = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"];
return arr[(val % 16)]
println(arr)
```

Results in 'String' is not convertible to '()' with the line return arr[(val % 16)].
I am sure I am just missing one simple thing but I am stumped.

Comment: Part of my issues is I had the fist two lines messed up so I was getting a nil value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One certain problem and one likely—you need to use an `Int` for your array index:

```
return arr[Int(val % 16)]
```

The error message sounds to me like you didn't declare a return type for your function:

```
func getWindDirection() -> String {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: var deg  = wind["deg"] as Double
var val = ((deg / 22.5) + 0.5);
var arr = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"];
return arr = [Double(val % 16)]  And I am not trying to go back to a func. The value is a double so now what is your best guess for the format of the return arr[Double(val % 16)] line?

Comment: `arr` is an `Array<String>` - an array whose contents are all of type `String`. Subscripting will get out a single `String` instance. If this code *isn't* part of a function, the `return` keyword doesn't make sense here - if you want to put the direction (e.g., "NNE") in another variable, you'd use `var direction = arr[Int(val % 16)]`.

Comment: And yes, `val` is a `Double`, but you can *only* use an `Int` to subscript an array. That's why I gave the first code sample: it converts the double to an integer.